# Tracking history for account team object in salesforce

Tags: administration

I want to track the changes done to my account team object similar to account hsitory . Can any one suggest the best method possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You could create a custom object to hold these data changes.  Then create a trigger on the AccountTeamMember object and insert the changes into your custom object.

So for instance on your custom object lets call it AccountTeamHistory__c, you have the following fields

```
Date - Date of the transaction
Action - The DML action that occurred, Insert, Update, Delete, etc. 
Member - The contact that was added updated, deleted, etc. 
Before_Role - The role before the action    
After_Role - The role after the action
```

In your trigger you simply create a new instance of this custom object and populate the fields with the values from the trigger context variables and insert the new object.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the Standard Objects and Custom Objects supports "History tracking".

Apparently, "Account Team" object does not support Field History tracking.

If you want comprehensive tracking solution, then we can use Triggers on that particular object and use the old maps and new maps to capture information.

Edit: Corrected my answer as @Dunc44 pointed out my mistake.

Comment: Try to follow your own instructions.  That execution path does not exist.  This is not possible for the account team object.  The question is asking for an alternative because it isn't possible.